# Mostrar badge na borda de um botão

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho um botão e um badge com o valor sendo atualizado com JQuery, quero que o badge fique na borda do botão.

Alguém sabe como configurar?

Comment: PRV seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, pra melhorar a qualidade da resposta, sugiro que adicione o código que já tens no corpo da pergunta, clique no botão [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/80631/edit) logo abaixo da sua pergunta para adicionar essas informações. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para se familiarizar com o site.

Comment: Com CSS: `float:right`

Comment: Fala Diego.. grato pela ajuda.. Com esta configuração o badge fica no lado direito.. mas não tenho visual esperado.. Gostaria que o badge ficasse em cima da borda do botão..metade para dentro do botão e metade para fora.. entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem 'n' formas de fazer o que você quer, a que considero mais "limpa" e de manipulação/manutenção simples é ter essas regras definidas:

```css
.badge-button {
  position: relative
}

.badge-button:after {
  /* O conteúdo exibido será o valor definido no atributo 'data-badge'. */
  content: attr(data-badge);
  position: absolute;
  top:   -8px;
  right: -10px
}

/**
 * Técnica para esconder o conteúdo :after caso o atributo
 * 'data-badge' seja vazio. 
 */
.badge-button[data-badge='']:after {
  display: none
}
```

E no seu HTML, o botão (ou qualquer elemento que seja) ter o [atributo customizado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) **`data-badge`**:

```
<button class='badge-button' data-badge='10'>mensagens</button>
```

Como está utilizando jQuery, pode utilizar a função [**`data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para manipular o atributo e alterar seu valor.

As regras acima já fazem ele ficar na posição que você gostaria — pelo "configurar" que usou na pergunta, considerei que o problema era o posicionamento. Mas ainda assim segue um exemplo com um visual melhor aplicando essas propriedades:

```css
.badge-button {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    outline: 0
}

.badge-button:after {
    content: attr(data-badge);
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: -10px;
    background: #34495e;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: .8em
}
```

```html
<button class='badge-button' data-badge='10'>notificações</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado!! vou testar a solução e digo se está OK!!!

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste!!! Funcionando 100%. grato pelo suporte. Abs